# C++ Cannot read words from a txt file

Tags: c++, file, class, text, readfile

I'm currently trying to write a program which will read words from a text file. Finally I plan to read certain words from a file and so on but at the moment I can't get my current code to work.

I have 3 files. Header file, main file and implementation file.

ReadWords.h

```
#ifndef READWORDS_H
#define READWORDS_H
/**
* ReadWords class. Provides mechanisms to read a text file, and return
* capitalized words from that file.
*/
using namespace std;

#include <string>
#include <fstream>

 class ReadWords
 {
   public:
    /**
     * Constructor. Opens the file with the default name "text.txt".
     * Program exits with an error message if the file does not exist.
     */
     ReadWords();

    /**
     * Constructor. Opens the file with the given filename.
     * Program exits with an error message if the file does not exist.
     * @param filename - a C string naming the file to read.
     */
     ReadWords(char *filename);

    /**
     * Closes the file.
     */
     void close();


   // working storage.
   private:
     string nextword;
     ifstream wordfile;
     bool eoffound;

 };

 #endif
```

ReadWords.cpp

```
#include "ReadWords.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//:: Defines function as member of class.


ReadWords::ReadWords(char *filename)
{
    ifstream str;
    str.open("hamlet.txt");
    char c;
    while ((c = str.get()) !=EOF){
        cout << c << endl;
    }
}

void close()
{

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "ReadWords.h"

int main()
{
    ReadWords rw;
    rw.ReadWords("hamlet.txt");
}
```

Now I know I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I'm not 100% sure what.
The error I receive in compilation is as follows:

```
main.cpp: In function `int main()':
main.cpp:6: error: invalid use of `class ReadWords'
```

Tool completed with exit code 1

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: always look at the first error you get - "#include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>" and examine that line. If you googled you would have got several hints about what you were doing wrong...

Comment: Which resource are you using to learn C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main.cpp, you missed the quotes in the `#include ReadWords.h` directive. To fix this you should use `#include "ReadWords.h"`.

Also, you should note that `std::istream::get` returns only a character. If you want to read a whole word in a (for example) `std::string`, you should use `std::istream::operator >>` like this:

```
std::ifstream in("my_file");
std::string word;

if (in.is_open()) {
    while (in >> word) {
        //do something with word
    }
}
```

Another thing that stands out is that in `rw.ReadWords("hamlet.txt")` you're calling a constructor as if it were a member function. The proper way to use that overload is: `ReadWords rw("hamlet.txt")`.

As a side note: the constructor's job is to initialize the object. It's not a good practice to do more than that inside it's body.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the very first error from the compiler, the first line of main.cpp

```
#include ReadWords.h
```

needs to be:

```
#include "ReadWords.h"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, no idea how I didn't notice this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
#include "ReadWords.h"
```

or

```
#include <ReadWords.h>
```

Comment: I would avoid the second form for user-made headers.

Comment: There may be some cases where you can use it - http://c-faq.com/cpp/incl.970605.html

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to add a ";" after rw.ReadWords("hamlet.txt") in main.cpp. That is the meaning of the last line of your compiler output.

Comment: first off he needs to re-read the textbook.... or basic tutorial

Answer (score 0):

This seems needlessly complicated. Won't this do?

```
vector<string> words;
string word;
while(cin >> word)
    words.push_back(word);
```

Comment: Won't work if you start with `#include vector` :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous mistakes in your programming:

1. close the file that you have opened. Always remember this, it may cause run-time errors.
2. in the main.cpp file it is #include "ReadWords.h" in the first line
3. Put a semi-colon at the end of the code line: rw.ReadWords("hamlet.txt");

Comment: ifstream's destructor will close the file. It will not cause any runtime errors.